# How to check whether port 25 is open or not from ssh access to server

Tags: ssh, smtp

I have ssh access to my Linux server and I want to check whether port 25 open or not.

I discussed with hosting service provide and they said port 25 is open.

I checked using PHP script for port 25 and it says it is open.

I want to know how to check using command on linux server like in Windows I can use `telnet example.com 25`

Any idea?

Comment: Does `telnet example.com 25` not work for you?

Comment: I was testing on linux server, I didn't got response after telnet, so I thought it is for only windows.

Answer (score 1):

You should check it from your home PC or another computer than your Linux server. you can use several tools like **telnet**, **curl**, **netcat** (nc) etc.

**curl:**

```
$ curl ip_or_domain:25
```

**netcat:**

```
$ nc ip_or_domain 25
```

in any case if you got `220 hostname SMTP Mail Server` this shows that the port is open.

Comment: When I am doing then getting error as "curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server" and nc mydomain.com 25 shows no output

Comment: `nc` doesn't print out information to `stdout` but you could check its response like `nc ip_or_domain 25 && echo $?` if it is 0=> success, if not => failure

Comment: @shahab82 what is the output of `curl ip_or_domain 25 -v`?